# SQL groupby rollup vs union

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union, rollup

Sql question:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q67X.png)
competitor  country
Acme Corp   USA
GLOBEX  USA
Openmedia   France
K-bam   USA
Hatdrill    UK
Hexgreen    Germany
D-ranron    France
Faxla   Spain
the output should be

country competitors
France  2
Germany 1
Spain   1
UK  1
USA 3
Total:  8
except using groupby with rollup, i am trying to solve it via "union" but turns out "order by is not functioning" (supposed to order by country name, but my output turns out to "order by competitors" ...)
This is my code:

```
(select country, count(competitor) as competitors
    from table
    group by 1
    order by 1 
    )
    union all
    (select "Total:" as country, count(*) as competitors from table);
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You have to put an ORDER BY at the end to order the final UNION ALL result.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, i.e. no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the result ordered, you need an `order by` *after* the `union`:

```
(select country, count(competitor) as competitors
 from table
 group by 1
) union all
(select 'Total:' as country, count(*) as competitors
 from table
)
order by (country = 'Total:') desc, country asc
```

Comment: This is brilliant!! thanks a lot, could you please explain why order by (country = "total") asc can make the "total:" row at the bottom? I'm still kinda confused at it

Comment: @Sheilalele . . . Booleans are treated as numbers in such contexts, with "true" as `1` and "false" as `0`.  So the `order by` puts the true values last (because of the `desc`).